# BUG cross-thread violation on rb_gc()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to work with ruby/rails but i got this error. Please help.

> [BUG] cross-thread violation on rb_gc() (null)
>
> Abort trap: 6

---

```
/opt/local/bin/ruby
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11]
```

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/fabiannothe/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**Update:**
I got this error on

> $ rails s

Comment: Could you provide some more context on how you got this to show up? Hopefully you're not just running `ruby` and seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacPorts, you may want to update that and re-install `ruby` through it. You may have a corrupted installation, especially if this used to work and is defective now.

That being said, you may want to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) to do the installation for you, as it generally patches the builds better.

Comment: i already re-installed ruby with macports. Still get the error

Comment: I'd give rvm a shot then just to try and narrow down the problem.